# Icons not showing in Ionic application

Tags: ionic4

I'm getting an issue with Ionic icon. I am using Ionic 4 and Angular 8, trying to add QR code icon, without luck.

I am using Ionic doc: https://ionicons.com/

```
<ion-menu-toggle auto-hide="false">
       <ion-item (click)="scanBarcode()">
          <ion-icon name="qr-code-outline" slot="start"></ion-icon>
            <ion-label>
                Scan QR
            </ion-label>
       </ion-item>
</ion-menu-toggle>
```

Comment: If you want for browser , remove the www folder and build as ionic build --prod then ionic serve, and for mobile remove the platform then rebuild it. And check your icon names since also they have changed (ionicons.com)

Comment: Okay I will try and let you know

Comment: I tried for mobile by removing the platform, still no luck

Comment: Ok go inside the www folder and go to svg folder and search if the icon name exists. If it do not exist then you need to update the project icons, and if it exist also reply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using Ionic v4, but the Latest Version is Ionic v5. With this Major Upgrade the Icons changed also. When you are searching the Documentation about the ionic v4 Icons: https://ionicons.com/v4/