# Why ion-icon is not showing in ionic vue project?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic5, ionic-vue

I am trying to add icon with ion-icon in my ionic vue project. I copied code from [official page](https://ionicons.com/)

```
<ion-icon name="aperture-outline"></ion-icon>
```

here is my template

```
<template>
  <ion-content class="content">
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <ion-icon name="aperture-outline"></ion-icon>
    <h1>Hello2</h1>
  </ion-content>
</template>

<style scoped>
.content {
  --color: rgb(6, 114, 141);
  --background: rgb(240, 234, 234);
  --padding-top: 50px;
}
</style>
```

Here is my output

[image]

Why my icon is not showing?

N.B [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60650750/how-can-i-solve-the-issue-of-ionic-icons-not-showing-in-app) does not solve my problem

Comment: Does the `ion-icon` get the `hydrated` class after the render?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you need to update the naming convention for the icon it self -- the docs seem to be incorrect on this point, if I'm not mistaken.

So:

```
<ion-icon name="aperture-outline"></ion-icon>
```

becomes:

```
<ion-icon name="apertureOutline"></ion-icon>
```

Same with your import and return in your setup. This worked for me at least.

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace

```
<ion-icon name="aperture-outline"></ion-icon>
```

with

```
<ion-icon :icon="apertureOutline"></ion-icon>
```

and import the icon in the script section i.e.

```
import { apertureOutline } from "ionicons/icons";
```

As at the time of posting this answer, I'm not exactly sure there's an icon with the name in the question though